India long term capital gains (LTCG) - schedule SI
Here is a snippet of a return filed for AY 2023-24, generated by Indian Income tax website -

How did they get 6567 as tax ? (10% of 405289 is much greater)
I tried to look up "instructions", but only found Instructions_ITR2_AY2021_22.pdf , which was unclear. It only says:

The net capital gains
should be aggregated and will be auto populated to B4a and B7a of Schedule CG.
Thereafter, tax shall be charged at a flat rate of 10% in Schedule SI on the aggregate LTCG,
as reduced by Rupees One lakh, for the purpose of tax computation after giving benefit of
Rs. 1 Lakh each u/s 112A and 115AD(1)(b)(iii). This benefit of Rs.1 Lakh will be given in
Schedule SI.


There is a INR 1 lac exemption on long termc capital gan. Also if you are a resident, you can adjust the long term capital gain in the basic exemption limit (INR 2.5 lacs or INR 3 lacs per old/new tax regime)

Ah ok - so 10% of (CG + other income - 2.5L - 1L) matches the amount shown.
